TeX4ht doesn't work with bigfoot
I've been translating a book that contains regular footnotes (1, 2, 3, ...) and I'd like to include another set of footnotes for the translator (*, **, ***, would reset per page) — in other words I want to use multiple footnote series/apparatus in the book.
I managed to set up my Latex files with bigfoot to produce the desired result. But I'd like to generate an ebook by TeX4ht as well.
Unfortunately the generated ebook is broken because I guess there is no setup for bigfoot. How difficult would it be to generalize how TeX4ht handles footnotes and create a setup for bigfoot?
MWE
mwe.tex:
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[roman]

\begin{document}
    Hallooooooo.\footnoteA{first regular footnote}
    
    Foooooo.\footnoteA{second regular footnote}
    
    Bar.\footnoteB{some notes by translators}
    
    Baaaar.\footnoteB{some other notes by translators}
    
    \lipsum
    
    Hallooooooo.\footnoteA{third regular footnote}
    
    Foooooo.\footnoteA{fourth regular footnote}
    
    Bar.\footnoteB{some notes by translators on page 2}

    Baaaar.\footnoteB{some other notes by translators on page 2}
\end{document}

Compiled with:
$ tex4ebook -l mwe.tex -f epub3 "xhtml,fn-in"

Output
The underlying xhtml file doesn't even parse:
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element

Desired Output
Something like the usual output of inline footnotes in an ebook produced by Tex4ht but generalized to multiple footnote series — there are multiple blocks of footnotes (corresponding to different footnote series) at the end of a chapter:
-------
1. first regular footnote
2. second regular footnote
3. third regular footnote
4. fourth regular footnote

i. some notes by translators
ii. some other notes by translators
iii. some notes by translators on page 2
iv. some other notes by translators on page 2
-------

All with working back and forth links.
Note: I simplified the MWE and excluded the feature that the translators' footnotes reset per page, which seems to be a problem on its own and I will post a separate question on this.
Note2: I tried manyfoot as well but decided for bigfoot because it seems to be better. But I assume if there is a setup for bigfoot, it could be easily adapted to manyfoot.

I can confirm that Bigfoot doesn't work correctly with TeX4ht. I will try to fix it, but it can take some time, it seems that the code of the package is quite complex and I must finish some other stuff soon

@michal.h21 Thanks a lot! And don't worry about the time. The main thing for me is that it'll get done :)

Hi @michal.h21,
I hope you're doing well. I wanted to kindly check in regarding the TeX4ht and Bigfoot issue we discussed back in June. I've been working on a translation project that relies on these tools, and I'm wondering if there have been any updates or progress on the fix.
I really appreciate all the effort you put into resolving this, and I completely understand that these things can take time. Thank you again for your help and dedication!

I have found that bigfoot changes quite a lot of LaTeX internals, so it totally breaks TeX4ht footnote handling. Manyfoot isn't that intrusive, so I have found a workaround that seems to work.

I've finally found a way how to support bigfoot, see my updated answer.

The bigfoot package uses the Manyfoot package in the background, but redefines many of its commands and also modifies the output routine, which causes problems with TeX4ht. Since the changes in Bigfoot mainly affect the way footnotes are displayed, which is not of much interest to us in TeX4ht, we can prevent the loading of the package and instead just load Manyfoot. This way, we can define new types of footnotes that will work with the standard TeX4ht mechanism for displaying them.
I have already made the following changes to the TeX4ht source code, but I will also send them here so that you can try them out before they become available in TeX Live. Since we are adding support for commands that are used in the document preamble, we need to declare configuration files that will be loaded before the package is loaded. This can be achieved using declarations in the usepackage.4ht file. Here is how it should look like:
% usepackage.4ht (2024-11-05-11:19), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex

   \def\:temp{tex4ht}\ifx \:temp\@currname
   \:warning{\string\usepackage{tex4ht} again?}
   \def\:temp#1htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#2}}
\expandafter\:temp \@filelist htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty!*?: %
\ifx \:temp\empty  \else
   \:warning{if
    \string\RequirePackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} was
    used try instead, repectively,
    \string\RequirePackage{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage{hyperref}}
\fi

\fi
\gdef\a:usepackage{\use:package ,!*?: }
\gdef\use:package#1,{%
   \if :#1:\def\:temp##1!*?: {}\else
      \def\:temp{#1}\ifx \@currname\:temp
             \def\:temp##1!*?: {\input usepackage.4ht  }%
      \else \let\:temp=\use:package \fi
   \fi \:temp}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{titlesec.sty}{titlesec-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{multibib.sty}{multibib-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{biblatex-chicago.sty}{biblatex-chicago-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{cleveref.sty}{cleveref-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xr.sty}{xr-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xr-hyper.sty}{xrhyper-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{eso-pic.sty}{esopic-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{showframe.sty}{showframe-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{expl3.sty}{expl3-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{savetrees.sty}{savetrees-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{newcomputermodern.sty}{newcomputermodern-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{newcomputermodern.sty}{newcomputermodern-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty}%
{fontawesome5-utex-helper-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontawesome5.sty}{fontawesome5-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{biblatex.sty}{biblatex-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xeCJK.sty}{xecjk-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{unicode-math.sty}{unicode-math-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{ctex.sty}{ctex-hooks.4ht}
\AddToHook{class/ctexart/before}{\input{ctexart-hooks.4ht}}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{luatexja.sty}{luatexja-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{luatexja-fontspec.sty}{luatexja-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{polyglossia.sty}{polyglossia-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontspec.sty}{fontspec-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{tikz.sty}{tikz-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{pgf.sty}{pgf-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{pdfbase.sty}{pdfbase-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{pdfx.sty}{pdfx-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{lua-widow-control.sty}{lua-widow-control-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{tagpdf.sty}{tagpdf-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{tagpdf-base.sty}{tagpdf-base-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{accessibility.sty}{accessibility-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{embedfile.sty}{embedfile-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{breakurl.sty}{breakurl-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{hyperref.sty}{hyperref-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{bookmark.sty}{bookmark-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{draftwatermark.sty}{draftwatermark-hooks.4ht}
\AddToHook{package/tabu/before}{\RequirePackage{tabularx}}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{caption.sty}{caption-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{footnotebackref.sty}{footnotebackref-hooks.4ht}
\AddToHook{package/doc/before}{\SUPOff}
\AddToHook{package/doc/after}{\SUPOn}
\AddToHook{package/hypdoc/before}{\SUPOff}
\AddToHook{package/hypdoc/after}{\SUPOn}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{mathtools.sty}{mathtools-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{babel.sty}{babel-sty-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{minted.sty}{minted-sty-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xyling.sty}{xyling-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{graphics.sty}{graphics-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{graphbox.sty}{graphbox-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xcolor.sty}{xcolor-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{colortbl.sty}{colortbl-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{enumitem.sty}{enumitem-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{imakeidx.sty}{imakeidx-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fancyhdr.sty}{fancyhdr-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{exerquiz.sty}{exerquiz-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{hyperxmp.sty}{hyperxmp-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{datetime2.sty}{datetime2-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{manyfoot.sty}{manyfoot-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{bigfoot.sty}{bigfoot-hooks.4ht}


\endinput


There, we defined two files that will be loaded before the respective packages, bigfoot-hooks.4ht and manyfoot-hooks.4ht. In bigfoot-hooks.4ht, we prevent the Bigfoot package from loading and just load the Manyfoot package, so that we can declare new types of footnotes using the \DeclareNewFootnote command:
% bigfoot-hooks.4ht (2024-11-05-11:19), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
\:dontusepackage{bigfoot}
\RequirePackage{manyfoot}
\endinput

Now we need to add support for declaring footnotes in the manyfoot-hooks.4ht file:
% manyfoot-hooks.4ht (2024-11-05-11:19), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
\let\o:MFL@declare:\MFL@declare
\def\manyfoot:declarefn#1{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname footnote#1\endcsname[1]{%
    \stepcounter{footnote#1}%
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\csname thefootnote#1\endcsname}%
    \footnote{##1}%
  }%
}
\def\MFL@declare#1#2[#3]{%
  \o:MFL@declare:{#1}{#2}[#3]%
  \manyfoot:declarefn{#2}%
}%


}

\endinput


In the manyfoot-hooks.4ht file, we have redefined an internal macro that defines the footnote, so that it creates a command (like \footnoteA) that generates a standard footnote, but uses the counter and formatting command defined by Manyfoot. This gives us support for displaying the footnote in HTML, but with the correct number formatting.
This is the result:


Thank you very much! It seems to work well, and the solution looks elegant. I'll do more testing tomorrow. However, I have one more question: Is it possible to output the footnotes as indicated in the Desired Output? Specifically, I would like different levels of footnotes to be grouped together and separated by some vertical space. The manyfoot/bigfoot package does this on every page, so I thought it would be nice to replicate this at the chapter level as well.

@texrob grouping of footnotes would be much harder to implement. I can only think about grouping them using DOM filters.

Okay, I'll try to create a DOM filter tailored to my specific case.

I've done a lot of testing (which took more time than expected due to problems with hyperref), and it works well. However, I found one corner case: if I use manyfoot, I can use the existing footnote command for regular footnotes and define only the translator's footnotes with manyfoot. This approach produces the desired PDF, but TeX4ht gets confused about the footnote labels. Specifically, if I modify the MWE to use manyfoot instead of bigfoot and use footnote instead of footnoteA, footnotes 3 and 4 receive incorrect labels. Is it possible to support this corner case as well?

@texrob can you make a mwe for that? You can post it as a new question,.
